# ERROR: Cannot initialize Map with error UNKNOWN

Tags: here-api

Whenever I try to initialize the map, I always get the "error UNKNOWN" message.

I tried the examples from HERE, but I get the same error on all of them. So I made a very simple and clean application with the sole purpose of loading the map. It still doesn't work and I can't put my finger on it.

I'm using Android, trying to target version 4.4 (KitKat).
I am using the Premium SDK (during the 90 day trial).
I verified the app key, code and licence key many times now. They are absolutely correct.

The registered package name is

```
com.example.workywork
```

but in the manifest I have:

```
package="com.example.workywork.testherepremium"
```

(It was supposed to be a test, so don't mind the package name :) )
I think it is right, since they asked for package name, not for package name + project name.

Here is the code from my simple application:

Build.Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.workywork.testherepremium"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation (name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')
    implementation 'com.vividsolutions:jts:1.13'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

}
```

Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.workywork.testherepremium.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.here.android.mpa.common.GeoCoordinate;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.OnEngineInitListener;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MapFragment mapFragment;

    Map map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);

        mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {

                if (error == Error.NONE) {
                    map = mapFragment.getMap();
                    map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(49.259149, -123.008555),
                            Map.Animation.LINEAR);
                    map.setZoomLevel(13.2);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERROR: Cannot initialize Map with error " + error,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("mymsg", error.getStackTrace());
                    Log.e("mymsg", error.getDetails());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <!--Developers should put application credentials here.To obtain them, please register the application
        at https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid" android:value="-- app id --"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken" android:value="-- app token --"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key" android:value="-- license --" />

        <service
            android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
            android:label="HereMapService"
            android:process="global.Here.Map.Service.v3"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService.v3">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

I also tried to use

```
android:process="global.Here.Map.Service.v2"
```

with

```
android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
```

or

```
android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService.v2"
```

Or any other such combination.

What am I missing?

As you can see, I've been struggleing with this for a couple of days now ;)
Thank you very much for your help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `applicationId` has to match the registered name exactly (in your case `com.example.workywork`). Otherwise, I can't spot an issue with the code you've posted.

You can try following this guide: [Creating a Simple Application Using the HERE SDK](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
I assumed so, but it worked perfectly with the basic SDK.
I'll try another approach today and post the results.

Comment: Thank you once again. I finally managed to make it work.

For all of us who make a distinction between package and project name, the registered package name must include the project's name.
In my case `com.example.workywork.testherepremium`

The weirdest part is that it worked perfectly with the Basic SDK, even if the registered package name was obviously wrong.